# Array Diff, compare 1d array to 2d arrays second dimension

Tags: php, arrays

```
array_diff( $files, $data[ ][0] )
```

**Is it possible** to compare them by only the value stored inside [0] position and iterate through the empty [ ] ?

**My problem** is that my `$data` array is a 2d array and `$files` is a 1d array. The `Y` coordinate of `$data` contains the `X` coordinate of `$files`.

**This is essentially what I'm looking for**

```
// How I need array_diff to compare them. 
$files[0] -> $data[0][0]
$files[1] -> $data[1][0] // Y is constantly position 0, while both X's remain at the same position.
```

**If this is impossible** to make happen using a pre-made `php` function, what's the best way to solve this? I really don't want `$data` to be a 2d array, all I need is the Y coordinate value to be set to the x coordinate value and get rid of the extra dimension of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but you can probably try this.

```
$diffs = array_diff($files, array_map(function($a){ return $a[0]; }, $data));
```

Another way could be:

```
$diffs = array();
foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
    if ($data[$key][0] != $value) {
        $diff[] = $files[$key]; // if you want to check the value of the files variable
        $diff[] = $data[$key][0]; // for the data variable
    }
}
```

I don't know the differences in performance, but the latter one works only if `$files[$n] == $data[$n][0]` So if i had to guess the latter one will be faster in performance.

Comment: By golly that fixed it exactly! Is this really an efficient way to do it though ?

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure, but the code looks clean and its pretty solid. Efficiency is always difficult because I can only give suggestions based on the little information I got. But I added another option which i think is faster, but has its limitaions in usage.

Comment: You can write other custom alternatives for array_diff which make it faster, like this guy did http://blog.my-helper.com/php/improve-performance-of-array_diff/